# animate.css bounceindown not working in safari

Tags: css, safari, jquery-animate

The animation is not working in safari.

```
@media screen and (min-color-index:0) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  @media {
    img.img-responsive.padd-bottom.desktop {
      display: none;
    }
    .col-md-10.col-sm-10.ftr.clearfix.animated.animated-delay-15s.bounceInDown.safari_only {
      animation-duration: 5s !important;
      animation-delay: 15s !important;
      z-index: 9999;
      margin-top: -46%;
      margin-left: 290px;
      width: 60%;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 5s !important;
      -moz-animation-duration: 5s !important;
      -o-animation-duration: 5s !important;
      animation-duration: 5s !important;
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cleaned up code formatting

Answer (score 0):

```
    @-moz-keyframes bounce {
      0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
      }
      40% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
        transform: translateY(-30px);
      }
      60% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(-15px);
        transform: translateY(-15px);
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes bounce {
      0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
      }
      40% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
        transform: translateY(-30px);
      }
      60% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
        transform: translateY(-15px);
      }
    }
    @keyframes bounce {
      0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
      }
      40% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
        transform: translateY(-30px);
      }
      60% {
        -moz-transform: translateY(-15px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
        transform: translateY(-15px);
      }
    }
    body {
      background: black;
    }

    .arrow {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -20px;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
      background-size: contain;
    }

    .bounce {
      -moz-animation: bounce 2s 1;
      -webkit-animation: bounce 2s 1;
      animation: bounce 2s 1;
    }
    <div class="arrow bounce"></div>
```